# Regex match and replace advanced

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm trying to write a little WordPress plugin to support some migrated content.

The syntax highlighter expects (for proper highlighting):

```
<pre lang='something'>
  <code>
    The code...
  </code>
</pre>
```

However, my markdown code has the following:

```
<pre>
  <code>
    :::something
    The code...
  </code>
</pre>
```

I think you can see where this is going. What I want to achieve is this:

1. `:::something` should be removed, and the `<pre>` tag should be updated to `<pre lang="something">`.
2. If `:::something` does not exist, the `<pre>` tag should be `<pre lang="plain">`
3. There may be multiple occurrences per page that need to be updated.

How would a PHP function achieving the above look like?

```
function set_syntax_lang($content) {
  // Do stuff here
  return $new_content;
}
```

What I gathered so far is this regex:

```
/<pre.*>\s*<code>\s*:::(\w)/
```

This even yields me, using `preg_match`, the actual syntax indicator (`something`), but I don't know how to update the `pre`-tag correctly.

It's been a very long time since I coded PHP and regexes are not really my strong suit. So all help is appreciated.

Comment: If you need to remove the end `</code>` then you can run into actual problems doing this with regex. You can try, but there is no guarantee this it won't break your output. Which languages are inside the code-block?

Comment: Okay not with that coffee-cup-swap-out scripts. Probably you should check the [SyntaxHighlighter Evolved](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/) Plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Finding :::something

```
preg_replace( '/<pre(.*>\s*<code>\s*):::(\w+)/U', '<pre lang="$2"$1' , $html );
```

This is an edge-case. But normally I should advise you to NOT use regex for html (bobince someone?).

Also next time try be less verbouse on your question. I took more time to read you than to write this answer.

### Finding code without :::something

```
preg_replace( '/<pre(.*>\s*<code>\s*)(?!:::\w+)/U', '<pre lang="plain"$1' , $html );
```

### Fixing `<code>`

```
preg_replace( array( '/(<pre.*>)\s*<code>/U' , '/<\/code>\s*(<\/pre>)/U' ),
              '$1' , $html );
//> Completly untested
```

Comment: untested. tell me if there are problems

Comment: (\w) should be (\w+), then it works. But now <code>..</code> is shown as the actual code. Seems I need to remove those <code> tags as well. Still not working for a missing `:::something` though. Looking into that now.

Comment: what do you mean by actual code? Also yes i totally forgot about that missing :::something give me a sec

Comment: @Ariejan: added the second regex you need for missing :::something

Comment: @yes123 that works nicely. I'm only left now with `<code>` and `</code>` in my actual code. (wp-syntax does not pick up the nested pre > code. I'll have to remove those myself, but I think I can manage that one.

Comment: I sitll don't understand what you need to do with your `<code>` Also if this helped you please think to +1

Comment: +1'd and considering this to accept as an answer. Here's the result I mean: http://staging.ariejan.net/2011/06/10/vows-and-coffeescript/

Comment: Ah ok so you just simply need to remove `<code>` tag? Is this all you need?

Comment: Yup, but without damaging actualy `<code>` tags in the code. The tags to be removed must be directly after and directly before the opening and closing `pre` tags.

Comment: I should get more than a merely +1 here :(

Comment: @Ariejan - what about using a plugin for that with shortcodes?

Comment: @yes123: I find it odd that you frequently overtext people with [the stupid link (mostly wrong, btw)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), yet handicraft a regex when it would actually have some relevancy for once. :>

Comment: @mario: I don't get if you are serious or not. If you think that link is stupid why are you posting it again here? Also did you read in my answer? I said `NOT use regex for html (bobince someone?)`. With **bobince** I was myself referring to that link. So no need to do a paternal here.

Comment: "You shouldn't do it - and here is the code on how to do it" always reads a bit amusing. But it very much invalidates the advise. And that specific link btw is widely [considered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73133/regex-and-html-the-long-tail-annoys-me/73168#73168) spam on stackoverflow. Will get flagged, and that's why it should be avoided usually. -- However, if you were to read the title once - it's about _nested tags_. And in this case OP asked about nested tags. So here it's the exception, and it would actually be a bit relevant (not the jokes, the technical answers below it.)

Comment: @mario: today do you have something against me or you missed the other regex answers? I can understand why. `Also if you were to read the title once - it's about nested tags` I don't know what questions you are referring but this question with this title isn't at atll about nested tags. Now can we stop the ot?

Comment: Nope. I was mostly expressing my amusement, and took the opportunity to post a note about the retarded link.

Comment: how can you say that's retarded while it's the most upvoted answer in the history? That's a true piece of poetry imo.

Comment: Can't get the WordPress filter working properly, too much hassle. Writing my own blog software using ruby ;-) @yes123 thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi guys, please don't use the commenting system as a chat room. It is for leaving a few comments and prods for more information to a question or answer, not for long debates. The reason behind this is that most of the time (and this is one of them), a lot if not all the comments belong as edits to the question/answer to make that more complete. If I have to read a half-page answer + 3 pages of comments, the focus on the comments is too big. Please edit in pertinent details into the answer instead. If you really need to chat, find/create a chat-room on the Chat site, link at the top of the page

Answer (score 1):

You answered most of your question in the steps you gave. Break it down into those chunks -- FIRST see if you have `:::something`, THEN update your `<pre>` tag and REPEAT.

You'll have a much easier time of it if you use the DOM instead of regex. It will make the job of navigating through the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags very simple. As has been said many, many times here, html is not a regular language, so a regular expression cannot parse it correctly. Even for a limited subset of HTML, it's really not the right tool. The regex for `:::something` is trivial once you use the DOM to get the text between `<code>` and `</code>`: `/:::(\w+)/`

Comment: I don't mean to come across as unwilling to answer what you asked -- I know how frustrating that can be. However, doing what you want is pretty much impossible in one regex (if you include things like having a default value), even smaller parts of it get ugly and unreadable quickly. Complex regexes are prone to typos and errors. I had to learn this the hard way...

Comment: My voting limit has reached, I think you make a valid point here about the limitation of regex'es for the purpose as well as for the hints for the regex formulation itself. So literally +1 and I keep the tab open in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

First of all some points I ran over:

```
/<pre.*>\s*<code>\s*:::(\w)/
     ^
```

According to your question, there never is a space in there if you make use of `:::something`. But you add it into your regex. I wonder why.

```
/<pre.*>\s*<code>\s*:::(\w)/
                         ^
```

If the language specifier is larger than one character (which I assume) you must write that into the regex, like `\w+` for one or more letters.

The rest looks quite like you have already everything. Probably not the replacement:

```
$result = preg_replace( '((<pre)(>\s*<code>\s*):::(\w+))', '$1 lang="$3"$2' , $subject );
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: was your preg_replace syntax a simple copy/paste of my first answer?

Comment: no, otherwise it would have had the mistakes you made in there. so should have been easy for you to see already as you corrected them based on my posting (at least obviously for the part you actually understood) - just kidding yes123 :D

Comment: actually the .* is necessary because the original html could have some other attr there (<pre class="ciao">). For this reason i left that there

Comment: well your regex actually matches tags like `<precaution` and various others. But that's something you can fix, I'm sure :)

Comment: yes I can fix it but there are no reasons since `<pre[a-z]+` doens't exists in HTML (not to talk about `<precaution`) ;) Now let's stop this stupid knowledge war